Why is Snowflake returning records where complex WHERE clause is FALSE?
I have this query in Snowflake (which runs on a generator so it doesn't need a table if you want to just run it):
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, SEQ4() * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) AS date_column,
    DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) as anchor_date,
    current_date,
    DATEADD(day, SEQ4() * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) AND CURRENT_DATE as truthy
FROM
    TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 5000))
WHERE
    DATEADD(day, SEQ4() * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) AND CURRENT_DATE
order by date_column

Which returns these records (and more):



date_column
anchor_date
current_date
truthy




2022-11-13
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
FALSE


2022-11-20
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
FALSE


2022-11-27
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
FALSE


2022-12-04
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
FALSE


2022-12-11
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
FALSE


2022-12-18
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
TRUE


2022-12-25
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
TRUE


2023-01-01
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
TRUE


2023-01-08
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
TRUE


2023-01-15
2022-12-13
2024-10-29
TRUE



Clearly it knows that the WHERE clause is FALSE for the first five records, but it returns those records anyway.  Why?  I'm guessing the table-free / generator setup may have something to do with it, but I can't figure out why.
I know I could wrap this in a SELECT * FROM () where truthy; - solving the problem isn't so much the issue as understanding why this doesn't work.  What's going on?

so first to prove the SEQ4 are stable in the select as implied:
SELECT
    SEQ4() * 7 as a,
    SEQ4() * 7 as b,
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 5000))
WHERE A != b


Query produced no results

good
now to use the results of the select region in the where:
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, SEQ4() * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) AS date_column,
    DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) as anchor_date,
    current_date,
    date_column BETWEEN anchor_date AND CURRENT_DATE as truthy
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 5000))
WHERE truthy
order by date_column


change back to using a seperate expression in the where clause (how you have it):
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, SEQ4() * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) AS date_column,
    DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) as anchor_date,
    current_date,
    date_column BETWEEN anchor_date AND CURRENT_DATE as truthy
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 5000))
WHERE DATEADD(day, SEQ4() * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) AND CURRENT_DATE
order by date_column


I am going to guess the independant code is the same as explicitly using a sub-select:
SELECT
    DATEADD(day, SEQ4() * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) AS date_column,
    DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) as anchor_date,
    current_date,
    date_column BETWEEN anchor_date AND CURRENT_DATE as truthy
FROM (
    select SEQ4() as sub_seq
    from TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 5000))
) WHERE DATEADD(day, sub_seq * 7, '2022-11-13'::DATE) BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -98, CURRENT_DATE) AND CURRENT_DATE
order by date_column

which has unwanted results which can be seen like this:
SELECT
    SEQ4() as a,
    a > 1000 as assumptions
FROM (
    select SEQ4() as b
    from TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 5000))
) 
WHERE b > 1000
order by 2;


Now if the where clause here was a != b there are no unwanted results, as the rows are only processed once.

Oooh, interesting @simeon-pilgrim.  What really cements it for me is editing your final query to add b in the top SELECT statement.  This shows that the two SEQ4() calls differ.  (I see values like A=673, B=1674.  Off by 1001 is probably not a coincidence.  This makes it clear the engine is doing something quirky, but does it explain it?  Is there a Snowflake doc that indicates guaranteed (or not) behavior here?  I see the note here about gaps, but that doesn't seem to be my issue. Very enlightening, though, thank you.

well, the SEQ is a operators, that works on the row level, if the process is split across "two steps" two non-related SEQ (not reusing the alias of one in the other) the optimization has privilege to use different SEQ as logically the values are non-explicitly tied together. This is a bug bear of mine, that people like to write the same SQL twice, because other DB's force you to, where snowflake allows use aliases anywhere the resultant could be scoped, thus tell the optimizer what you mean. So I always use aliases. It also tells other dev's what you are doing, I chose explicit vs implicit

I also thought I was explicilty showing b was different.. by the presence of the results, but I see I did not show it.
